# Laravel CRUD delete route parameters

Tags: php, laravel

Id' like to use a CRUD Controller to handle the admin profile. I created the Controller and edited my routes/web.php like this.

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => ['auth:admin']], function(){
    Route::resource('profile', 'ProfileController')->only(['index', 'edit', 'update', 'destroy']);
});
```

This creates the following routes.

```
admin/profile -> admin.profile.index
admin/profile/{profile} -> admin.profile.destroy
admin/profile/{profile} -> admin.profile.update
admin/profile/{profile}/edit -> admin.profile.edit
```

Since I get the admin_id through the session I don't need to get it through the URL via the profile parameter. I know that I could just ignore the parameter, but it makes the URL unnecessary long.
Is there a chance to delete the {profile} parameter from the routes, so that my routes are like **teacher/profile/edit** and not like **teacher/profile/12345678/edit**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use separate routes instead of resource for your individual operation.
Like

```
For index operation you can use:-
Route::get('profile', 'ProfileController@index');
For destroy operation you can use:-
Route::delete('profile', 'ProfileController@destroy');
For edit operation you can use:-
Route::put('profile', 'ProfileController@edit');
```

And you can send your admin_id  in input or from session.
Hope it will work for you :)

Answer (score 1):

- Yes you can remove that perticular parameters from route.
- but instead on this you have to send profile data through post variable
- This is not possible to send post data in every redirection.

**I will suggest you to use 'Slugs' instead of profile id**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can remove the `{profile}` part if you call the profile needed first in the controller like such:

```
public function edit(){
    $teacher = Auth::user();
    return view('teacher.profile.edit', compact('teacher'));
}
```

And inside the view page (teacher/profile/edit), you can call the data like such:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('teacher.profile.update', $teacher->id) }}">
    @method('PATCH')
    @csrf
    ID: <input type="text" name="id" value={{ $teacher->id}} />
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

I hope this help. Cheers!